# How can I turn off "suggestions table?" in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to turn off the part that I marked with red. Could you please help? (Only want to bottom part to be appear.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your settings.json:

"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false